# How electricity is consumed

Tags: electricity

I'm trying to understand something about electricity. Is electricity being wasted when you use it? 
I mean when you use an electrical appliance, you need to plug it into a socket right? So you create a circle, where electricity goes into your device and returns back into socket... So does any of electricity actually wasted by the device, or does it just go through the device? 
Understand what I mean? What the difference between electricity traveling through power cables, or traveling through a TV or a washing machine?

Comment: It is all about the basics of power and work - start with the physics book. A power is "consumed" in such a sense, that "energy is converted from one form to another". Typically, current that flows through circuit is dissipated as EMI radiation and heat. But there may be other forms of conversion, to mechanical work or to supply a chemical reaction. And there are debates: "Does matter or energy ever disappears?" But that is on a stellar scale: When a two black holes collide, their summary mass is less than sum of both and radiation emitted, and we cant exactly find out where does it gone.

Comment: Maybe they underestimate the spectrum of the emission and do not have sensors with adequate bandwidth to detect it.

Comment: Heat is generated. Your power bill rises. Using the convected air flow from audio-power-amplifier heatsinks, in the winter-time, is a use for that low-grade (low rise above ambient) heat.

Comment: Checkout TimWescott's answer to the duplicate that's been linked, I suspect that's the best answer to your confusion.

Comment: Let me ask you this... There is electricity in the power cables right? When I plug my TV, what changes? Does it cause the voltage in power cables to slightly drop or what?